# Choose what updates to install

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

When I check for updates on Windows 10, the system starts to install automatically all the updates found. Is there any way to choose before installing updates like in previous windows versions?

Comment: [Short answer, No.](http://www.howtogeek.com/223068/what-you-need-to-know-about-windows-update-on-windows-10/)

Comment: This look strange , because what about if I don't want to install a driver update that cause problems on my system ?If I let the system to install this driver , after I will have problems and maybe I will bot be able to rollback the driver ?

Comment: Ask Microsoft, you can delay the driver install but not opt out permanently, stupid I know but I don't make the rules. Microsoft is going to drive many users to Linux because of this nonsense.

Comment: use GPOs to force Windows 10 to show you a toast when new updates are available. Follow the duplicate link for the steps.

Comment: @tiku - Microsoft released a tool to block device driver updates in that case.  Windows 10 Home installations have must install All updates, except those they block with said tool, but otherwise there is no way to select which updates to install.